# Getting error while fetching details with web scraping in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am getting Error while scraping data from a site please if anyone could help me with that
my Code

```
html = requests.get('https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/btc/influence/USDT').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
total_commit = soup.select_one('  # col-body > div > social-influence > div.row.row-zero.influence-others > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.col-md-3.td-col.brd-right > div > div.repo-tag > span > span > a').text
print(total_commit)
```

error

```
soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Malformed id selector at position 2
  line 1:
  # col-body > div > social-influence > div.row.row-zero.influence-others > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.col-md-3.td-col.brd-right > div > div.repo-tag > span > span > a
  ^
```

and  also if anyone can tell me how to use the Css selectors which we copy directly from inspect element in bs4.

Comment: Use their free API instead of scraping. https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/

Comment: @Vishnudev yeah i try gut the social API is not working in which they give name of git hub repos and url, I want that but in response is empty string in there API in key of Github url. this is there api https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/social/coin/latest?coinId=7605

Comment: They use the latest javascript technologies to render their website like Angular. Hence, direct scraping is not possible. You might wanna use Selenium/Scrapy for this.

Comment: If you wanna check why this doesn't work, just save the `html` string variable to a file `sample.html`. Then view in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by David Miró removing whitespace will fix the `error` but to get your goal you have to deal with [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

`Selenium` will render the website and you can inspect the `page_source` and select your Element with `bs4`:

```
soup.select_one('div.repo-tag a')['href']
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('YOUR PATH TO DRIVER')
driver.get('https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/btc/influence/USDT')

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

soup.select_one('div.repo-tag a')['href']
```

#### Output

```
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
```

Comment: thanks it worked but what to give inside select_one function like you have given ```div.repo-tag a```  how can i find this for different element

Comment: That is still specific and you should always take a look into your soup - There is the truth. Approache is this -> If element is unique or has an unique identifier (id, class, attribut) select it directly, else try to select the next unique element that contains your element and build chain to your tag/element.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing space between `#` and `col-body`.

```
html = requests.get('https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/btc/influence/USDT').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
total_commit = soup.select_one('#col-body > div > social-influence > div.row.row-zero.influence-others > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.col-md-3.td-col.brd-right > div > div.repo-tag > span > span > a').text
print(total_commit)
```

But it doesn't work because a part of the html is generated by javascript. So, you need to simulate that you are a web browser (for example with Selenium):

```
 <div class="col-body col-body-new" id="col-body" ui-view>
        <div class="loader-ccc">
    <div class="loader-ccc-logo"></div>
    <div class="loader-ccc-sides"></div>
 </div>
```

In the web browser information exists:

[image: from web browser]

Comment: No not working output should be : https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

Comment: The problem is that a part of the html is generated by javascript. So, you need to simulate that you are a web browser (for example with Selenium).